# Custom Artist In Matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a program using PtQt that utilizes matplotlib to do some plot rendering.  For saving images, I would like to make use of the legend to render a custom image (additionally the built-in draggable feature makes this very appealing).  I'm reading up on the legend, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a legend that calls my own paintEvent() method for Qt in which I can render custom images.

In case this approach is terrible, here's my goal:  I want to put a image (rendered inside the program by Qt) either inside the plot window or find a way to append this image on top of the exported figure.

Here's a screenshot of what the output looks like now:

[image]

I'd like to take the DAIP... sequence at the top and have that exported with the figure.

Hopefully someone has tackled a similar problem before.

Comment: Screenshot missing. Sounds like you just want an image in the Figure, right? Does http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figimage do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the OffsetImage and AnnotationBBox features of matplotlib after saving the image to a temporary png file.  For some reason keeping it as a temporary file didn't work well.

Briefly:

```
#draw stuff onto QPixmap named pix
byteArray = QByteArray()
buffer = QBuffer(byteArray)
buffer.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
pix.save(buffer, 'PNG')
stringIO = StringIO(byteArray)
stringIO.seek(0)
tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", mode="wb", delete=False)
tfile.write(stringIO.buf)
tfile.close()
imagebox = mpl.offsetbox.OffsetImage(mpl._png.read_png(tfile.name),zoom=zlvl)
ab = mpl.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(imagebox, [w/2,0],frameon=False)
ab.set_figure(self.canvas.figure)
ab.draggable()
self.subplot.axes.add_artist(ab)
os.remove(tfile.name)
```